# Django ModelForm validate if input exists in model

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-forms

I have a model *Linea* with only one field named *numero*, wich is a charset (the values of *numero* are supposed to be numbers) . I want to do a form where the user can search for a value of *numero*. If the number that the user inputs exists in the database the view will redirect to a template that shows information about that value of *numero*, but if the value that the user search is not in the database it will throw an error.

I'm very new in Django, and I've searched the way to do it but I can't achieve it.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Linea


class LineaForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Linea
        fields = ('numero',)
```

**models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


class Linea(models.Model):
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=2)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.numero
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from .forms import LineaForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime

def lineas(request, template="bustopaplineas.html"):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LineaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            numero = form.save(commit=False)
            linea_numero = str(numero)
            return redirect('lineas_detalles', linea_numero=linea_numero)
    else:
        form = LineaForm()
    return render(request, 'bustopapp/lineas.html', {'form': form})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the **Linea** table if it exists or not:

```
Linea.objects.get(numero=input)
```

In case, it doesn't it will throw an exception